# What is the appropriate structure to represent a GLFWwindow handle returned be CreateWindow in ctypes.func.argtypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, glfw

I have a simple program in `glfw`, which uses `glfw.glfwSetCursorPos` to put the mouse in a certain spot on the screen. However, it was raising a lot of errors, until I found this thread: [ctypes.ArgumentError: Don't know how to convert parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43317409/12692182). Now, it works, but one of its parameters is the returned value from `glfw.CreateWindow` that you want to center on. But, following the accepted and only answer on that thread, I have no idea what variable in `ctypes` I should use to represent the window in the argtypes for that function, if there even is a variable for a glfw window. And if there isn't one, is there any other way to fix my original problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is a minimal reproductible example. The moment you move the mouse, you can see that it starts spamming to `sys.stderr`:

```py
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *
import glfw
glfw.glfwInit()

def onMouseMove(win2, x, y):
    print(x, y)
    glfw.glfwSetCursorPos.argtypes = [glfw.GLFWwindow,
                                      ctypes.c_float,
                                      ctypes.c_float]
    glfw.glfwSetCursorPos(win, float(50), float(50))

glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)
glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

win = glfw.glfwCreateWindow()

glfw.glfwMakeContextCurrent(win)

glfw.glfwSetInputMode(win, glfw.GLFW_CURSOR,
                      glfw.GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED)

glfw.glfwSetCursorPosCallback(win, onMouseMove)

while not glfw.glfwWindowShouldClose(win):
    glfw.glfwPollEvents()
glfw.glfwTerminate()
```

Comment: Please tell me if there is anything else relevant you think I should add to my question, for example, my OS, or my `glfw` version

Comment: I think it should be struct? Worse case, just try all the ctypes, shouldnt be too many. Check this page out. See typedef struct GLFWwindow https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__window.html#ga3c96d80d363e67d13a41b5d1821f3242

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it wants an instance of `GLFWwindow`, and it says I pass it an LP_GLFWwindow. I'll try to do a bit more browsing in the docs, see if I can find anything

Comment: Can you see if the following answer has any help for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993078/looking-for-a-simple-opengl-3-2-python-example-that-uses-glfw

Comment: Thanks, but it does not. This is what I originally built my code off of, and my problem is about how to safely execute `glfw.glfwSetCursorPos`, not have a simple example of a rotating star.

Comment: Well, then I need to have a look at your code snippet to help any further.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. My answer is below

Comment: You don't have to specify anything. *glfw* already does that.

Comment: Then why was it not working?

Comment: I don't know. You didn't specify what is not working. also when I tried to run your code, I got an error at `glfw.glfwInit()` (nit found). Don't know what you're doing there (also those *OpenGL* imports don;t seem to be needed).

Answer (score 0):

`glfwCreateWindow` returns a handle to your window. As far as I know, this handle is not represented by any sort of library out there, even `glfw`. Thankfully, there is a `builtin` python function that will allow you to create an argument passable to `argtypes`, `type`. As far as I know, this only works with the current context, but it does work:

```
glfw.glfwSetCursorPos.argtypes = [
                                  type(self.win) # or whatever else your window is named
                                  ctypes.c_float
                                  ctypes.c_float]
```